# How to render extra components inside a component after button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have blogposts that I need to render. The first 4 are shown. When clicking on the button underneath it, two more need to show up. When the button is clicked again, two more need to show up and so on.
Unfortunately, I am not able to do so.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Blogpost from './Blogpost.js';

class BlogpostReader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      blogposts: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Loading all blogposts in state
  }

  renderBlogpost(i) {
    // Render one blogpost
  }

//This function has to be replaced by one that renders extra blogposts
    showAlert(){
      alert("Im an alert");
    }

    render() {
      const {error, isLoaded} = this.state;
      if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
      } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      } else {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.state.blogposts.length && i < 5; i++) {
          this.state.renderedBlogposts.push(
            <div key={this.state.blogposts[i].id} className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 whole-blogpost">
              {this.renderBlogpost(this.state.blogposts[i])}
            </div>)
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="row">
              {this.state.renderedBlogposts}
            </div>
            <div className="centered-button">
              <button className="styled-button" onClick={this.showAlert}>Meer laden</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
  }

export default BlogpostReader;
```

How can I show extra blogposts after clicking the button? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
 import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Blogpost from './Blogpost.js';

    class BlogpostReader extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          blogposts: [],
          count:5
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        // Loading all blogposts in state
        if(blogposts.length<5){
          this.setState({
            count:blogposts.length
          })
        }
      }
      renderBlogpost(i) {
        // Render one blogpost
      }
      renderBlogposts(){
        const blogposts=[];
        const count=this.state.count;
        for (let i = 1; i < count; i++) {
          blogposts.push(
            <div key={this.state.blogposts[i].id} className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 whole-blogpost">
              {this.renderBlogpost(this.state.blogposts[i])}
            </div>)
        }
        return blogposts;
      }

    //This function has to be replaced by one that renders extra blogposts
        addMore=()=>{
          let newCount=this.state.count + 2;
          if(this.state.count===this.state.blogposts.length) return;
          if(this.state.count+1 === this.state.blogposts.length){
            newCount=this.state.count+1
          }
          this.setState({
            count:newCount
          })
        }

        render() {
          const {error, isLoaded} = this.state;
          if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
          } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
          } 

            return (
              <div>
                <div className="row">
                  {this.renderBlogposts()}
                </div>
                <div className="centered-button">
                  <button className="styled-button" onClick={this.addMore}>Meer laden</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need more explanation in this

Comment: There could be a class added to the button to hide it when the all the posts are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Oh no honey. In React the recommended approach is to make things as declarative as possible. Which means that instead of imperatively pushing items onto an array and then render that array you can just render a slice of the array.

I.e. try something like this

```
class BlogpostReader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      blogposts: [], // this will contain all posts
      postsToShow: 2, // a simple number controls how many posts are shown
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Loading all blogposts in state
  }

  increasePostsShown() {
    this.setState(({ postsToShow }) => {
      postsToShow: postsToShow + 1;
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, blogposts, postsToShow } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    const postsShown = blogposts.slice(0, postsToShow); // get only the ones you want to show
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {postsShown.map(blog => (
            <div>{blog}</div> {/* or display them however you like */}
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="centered-button">
          <button className="styled-button" onClick={this.increasePostsShown}>
            Meer laden
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your blogpost array containing already all the blog posts? My suggestion would be that everytime the user clicks on the button, you increment a value from the state.

```js
this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      blogposts: [],
      nbPostToDisplay: 4
    };
```

In your loop:

```js
for (let i = 0 /* start at 0, not 1 */; i < this.state.blogposts.length && i < nbPostToDisplay; i++) {
```

Some function to increment:

```js
function incrementNbPosts() {
  this.setState(prevState => return ({nbPOstsToDisplay: prevState.nbPostsToDisplay + 2});
}
```

Use function above in your button callback. This will trigger a re-render of your component.

IMPORTANT: do not forget to bind your functions in the construrtor or (better) use ES6 notation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's all you need. I also cleaned up your code a little bit

```
class BlogpostReader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      blogposts: [],
      limit: 4
    };
    this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this);
    this.renderBlogpost = this.renderBlogpost.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Loading all blogposts in state
  }

  renderBlogpost(i) {
    // Render one blogpost
  }

  //This function has to be replaced by one that renders extra blogposts
  showMore() {
    this.setState(state => ({ limit: state.limit + 2 }));
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, blogpost, limit } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>);
    }

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {
            blogposts.map((post, index) => {
              if (index + 1 !== limit) {
                return (
                  <div key={post.id} className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 whole-blogpost">
                    { this.renderBlogpost(post) }
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })
          }
        </div>
        <div className="centered-button">
          <button className="styled-button" onClick={this.showMore}>Meer laden</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to also make `showMore` to accept any number of posts, you can do this...

```
showMore(value = 2) {
  this.setState(state => ({ limit: state.limit + value }));
}
```

Then now you can call it with any number of posts you want. If you don't specify any value, the limit will be incremented by 2.

**UPDATE**

Since you've mentioned that you have to start when index is 1, then you can update your `blogposts.map` in the `render` like this

```
{
  blogposts.map((post, index) => {
    if (index && index !== limit) {
      // the condition above ensures that the posts at index 0, and also when index equals limit, are not returned

      // the rest of the code goes here...
    }
  })
}
```

After doing that, you can set limit to 5 in the constructor if you want to show only 4 entries at first load.

Comment: I do wonder, I have to start at blogposts[1] instead of blogposts[0] because of an error in the API. How can I manage to do so? Because this code seems to crash when trying to call renderblogpost()... 

I tried it at the (index + 1 !== limit) piece of the code, but that does not work. How can I manage this?

Comment: @Nynke have a look at the snippet below the **UPDATE** in my answer. That should do it

Comment: Hi Ladi, unfortunately it still gives me the following error after pressing the button: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined... This happens in the showMore() method... I am not sure why it cannot find the value of limit....

Comment: that's because we didn't bind the `showMore` in the constructor.  
Just do `this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this)` inside the constructor.
I have also edited the constructor in my answer to reflect this update...

Comment: Hmm this still does not work... I dont really understand why, I keep getting those errors and it keeps rendering all the blogposts

Comment: Can you share your code in a github gist and put the link here? Maybe I can take a look at it and tell you what’s wrong

Comment: The code as it is now does show 2 extra blogposts, but it also shows the first 4 again. I'm not sure why, but do you think the componenDidUpdate method can help?

Comment: Did you not want the first 4 to show after clicking on showMore? Are you looking for some sort of pagination instead?

Comment: I want the first 4 to be shown 'on startup' and when the button is clicked, I want the first 4 items to stay where they are, and to show 2 more items underneath them if that makes sense. That's why I, at first, just pushed to the array I had, which clearly didn't work haha

Answer (score 0):

I would better keep things simple, so that button would just set new `state.posts` with +1 post, thus triggering `render()`, that in turn will render added element.

```
 addPost = () => {
    ...
    this.setState({
      posts: [...posts, { id: posts.length + 1 }]
    });
  };

  renderPosts = () => {
    ...
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addPost}>Add</button>
        {this.renderPosts()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Made a quick sandbox illustrating provided code.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vjlp468jk7

Answer (score 0):

The following was the working code:

```
class BlogpostReader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      blogposts: [],
      limit: 5,
      start: 1
    };

    this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Loading all blogposts into state
  }

  renderBlogpost(i) {
    // Render a single blogost
  }

  showMore(){
    this.setState(state => ({
      start: state.limit,
      limit: state.limit + 2
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const {error, isLoaded, limit} = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      var startedAt = this.state.start
      for (startedAt; startedAt < this.state.blogposts.length && startedAt < limit; startedAt++) {
        this.state.renderedBlogposts.push(
          <div key={this.state.blogposts[startedAt].id} className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 whole-blogpost">
            {this.renderBlogpost(this.state.blogposts[startedAt])}
          </div>
        )
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.renderedBlogposts}
          </div>
          <div className="centered-button">
            <button className="styled-button" onClick={this.showMore}>Meer laden</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```